# React TypeScript Application gets 'TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.'

Tags: typescript

This is the dependencies in my package.json. this used to work for me in the past.

```
{
  "name": "login-ts-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/abhsrivastava/login-ts-react.git",
  "author": "Abhishek Srivastava <abhsrivastava@foo>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.3.13",
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.js looks like

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6"],
"module": "commonjs",
"jsx": "react",
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "./build",
"removeComments": true,
"strict": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": true,
"noImplicitThis": true,
"alwaysStrict": true,
"noUnusedLocals": true,
"noUnusedParameters": true,
"noImplicitReturns": true,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"baseUrl": "./src",
"esModuleInterop": true
```

When I do `yarn start` I get error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts:19:72
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:6:28
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'document'.
```

I had created an application last week with this very same package.json and it was working without these errors.

Edit:: Based on the answers below I tried two things

tsconfig.js

```
"target": "es6",
"lib": ["es6"],
"jsx": "react",
```

Now when I do yarn start I get error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts:19:72
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Text'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/index.tsx:5:28
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'document'.
```

I also tried

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6", "dom"],
"module": "commonjs",
```

Now I get error

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:2381:15
    TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URL'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:2399:15
    TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:2417:14
    TS2661: Cannot export 'URL'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts:2417:19
    TS2661: Cannot export 'URLSearchParams'. Only local declarations can be exported from a module.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
```

Comment: I wonder at which stage is the error thrown. Is it when you are trying to do `npm install` to install all the dependencies of the project?

Comment: when I do `yarn start`

Comment: Have you done `yarn install` first ?

Comment: yes. did `yarn install`.

Comment: Could you please show your .js or .ts code ?

Comment: https://github.com/abhsrivastava/login-ts-react

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went to the gitter channel of typescript and asked the question there. I got a solution which is working and I am listing it down here.

I needed to added `@types/node` version 9 to my package.json. So the working package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "login-ts-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/abhsrivastava/login-ts-react.git",
  "author": "Abhishek Srivastava <abhsrivastava@foo>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.3.13",
    "@types/node": "9.6.7", // <- right here
    "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.9",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
}
```

and the tsconfig.json looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"], // <- right here
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true, 
    "outDir": "./build",
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for react storybook.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably caused by the following setting in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
...
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6"],   <- right here
...
```

Here, you're explicitly telling the `tsc` you want to have `es5` javascript (`target` configuration). At the same time, you're saying you want to include the `es6` built in type declarations (and the `es6` built in type declarations *only*).

Now, this isn't a problem in itself, `tsc` will allow you to do that (though I would debate the point of this: your code will break on non es6 browsers unless you provide polyfills in your build pipeline). However, if you're telling `tsc` the `lib`s you want explicitly you have to make sure you don't forget any typings you will need in your App. Long story short, if you want to create a Web Application with Typescript, you typically also want to have the `dom` declarations in order to have access to DOM interface typings such as `document` or `Text`. The typescript developers decided to modularize built in library definitions [starting in typescript 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) (think of contexts where DOM type declarations make no sense, such as developing a node.js app!).

Here's how I'd advise you to change your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "es6",
"module": "commonjs",
"jsx": "react",
...
```

Getting rid of `lib` will give you the default: `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` (depending on the `target` you set). Since it seems you want to use `es6` in your project, set this as your transpilation target.

If you want to keep `es5` as your target, and also want to be explicit about `lib`, this should make your app compile (though I can't recommend this, for reasons stated above)

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["es6", "dom"]
"module": "commonjs",
"jsx": "react",
...
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions. Suggestion 1 still gets the same error. Suggestion two gets different set of errors. I updated my question with the error messages.

Answer (score 6):

make sure you are using .tsx for files having html tags.